# Eclipse Pydev and accepting incoming connections dialog in macOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, pydev

I am a user of Eclipse Neon on macOS el Capitan. After installing PyDev for Eclipse, I get a dialog asking about accepting incoming connections once per session.

I know about [Why does Eclipse want incoming network connections using OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516843/why-does-eclipse-want-incoming-network-connections-using-os-x) and [How to get rid of firewall accept incoming connections dialog](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/how-to-get-rid-of-firewall-accept-incoming-connections-dialog).

I tried the solutions in the second link to no avail. Moreover, for my development work I do not need the remote debugging capabilities of PyDev. Is there any way to turn them off or to otherwise prevent this dialog from appearing when I want to edit a Python file in Eclipse?

Conceptually, I believe, I have to sign the PyDev plugin for Eclipse, but this does not seem to be doable.

Comment: This is a duplicate either of [Why does Eclipse want incoming network connections (using OS X)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516843/why-does-eclipse-want-incoming-network-connections-using-os-x/40129838#40129838) or [How to get rid of firewall “accept incoming connections” dialog?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/how-to-get-rid-of-firewall-accept-incoming-connections-dialog) or [How do I stop my Mac from asking to accept incoming network connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/912656/how-do-i-stop-my-mac-from-asking-to-accept-incoming-network-connections) et al.

Answer (score 1):

I answered the **why** those connections are needed  in the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40129838/110451, as for getting rid of it, in my case just accepting it seems to work (so, unfortunately I can't really help you there as I don't experience the problem of accepting it and the Mac OS X firewall not acknowledging that properly -- seems like a Mac bug in the firewall for me).